# Как достать переменные из URL?

Tags: php, mysql

Добрый день. Пишу интернет магазин, по одному курсу, который нашел на просторах интернета. В одном моменте у меня выявилась загвоздка. Товары из БД выводятся полностью по всем категориям. Не захватывает в *url* переменные *cat* и *type* (например: `../viewCat.php?cat=canon&type=laserCartridge`):

```
$cat = $_GET['cat'];
        $cat = strip_tags($cat);
        $cat = mysql_real_escape_string($cat);
        $cat = trim($cat);
    $type = $_GET['type'];
        $type = strip_tags($type);
        $type = mysql_real_escape_string($type);
        $type = trim($type);
    if (!empty($cat) && !empty($type)){
        $querycat = "AND brand='$cat' AND type_product='$type'";
    }else{
        if(!empty($type)){
            $querycat = "AND type_product='$type'";
        }else{
            $querycat = "";
        }
    }
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE visible='1' $querycat ORDER BY $sorting",$link);
```

Comment: как вы узнали что он не захватывает? через print_f посмотрели?

Comment: @Konstantin, сюда по функциям `mysql_` ваш курс давно устарел и его пора на свалку отправлять.

Comment: <pre>$cat = $_GET['cat'];
  $cat = strip_tags($cat);
  $cat = mysql_real_escape_string($cat);
  $cat = trim($cat);
 $type = $_GET['type'];
  $type = strip_tags($type);
  $type = mysql_real_escape_string($type);
  $type = trim($type);
 if (!empty($cat) && !empty($type)){
  $querycat = "AND brand='$cat' AND type_product='$type'";
 }else{
  if(!empty($type)){
   $querycat = "AND type_product='$type'";
  }else{
   $querycat = "";
  }
 }
 print_f($querycat);
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE visible='1' $querycat ORDER BY $sorting",$link);</pre>

Comment: Вставил print_f($querycat); перед $result - ничего не выводит?!

Comment: printf($querycat); перед $reruslt не дает никакого результата, в прошлом примере была неправильная функция print_f - должна была ошибка отразиться типа undefinde , однако ничего не произошло. Что может все таки быть, в какую сторону смотреть?

Comment: Добавил перед $cat = $_GET['cat'];<br><pre> $db_host = 'localhost';
 $db_user = 'admin';
 $db_pass = '123';
 $db_database = 'db_shop';

 $link = mysql_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass);

 mysql_select_db($db_database,$link) or die("Нет соединения с БД ".mysql_error());
 mysql_query("SET names utf-8"); </pre>

Comment: Думал может дело в подключении добавил здесь же - итог - ничего не поменялось.

Comment: Вот думаю, может переменные $cat и $type нужно как-то обернуть, проверить в начале, типа isset? т.к. в пхп и майСиквел совсем новый человек, читаю все, что выдаёт Яндекс!

Comment: @webDev_ Добавил функцию проверки переменных - не помогло, может неправильно написал ее, конечно. Проверьте по-возможности:                                                                                            $cat = '';
 if (isset($_GET["cat"])){
  $cat = $_GET["cat"];
 }
 $cat = $_GET['cat'];
  $cat = strip_tags($cat);
  $cat = mysql_real_escape_string($cat);
  $cat = trim($cat);
$type = '';
 if (isset($_GET["type"])){
  $type = $_GET["type"];
 }

Comment: @Visman Мой вопрос размещен и в php и в mysql

Comment: @Konstantin, вы лучше предупреждение прочитайте: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-query.php Я вам не про теги комментарий писал.

Answer (score 0):

Это должно помочь вам выяснить что "захватывается", а что нет:

```
$cat = $_GET['cat'];
        $cat = strip_tags($cat);
        $cat = mysql_real_escape_string($cat);
        $cat = trim($cat);
    $type = $_GET['type'];
        $type = strip_tags($type);
        $type = mysql_real_escape_string($type);
        $type = trim($type);
    if (!empty($cat) && !empty($type)){
        $querycat = "AND brand='$cat' AND type_product='$type'";
    }else{
        if(!empty($type)){
            $querycat = "AND type_product='$type'";
        }else{
            $querycat = "";
        }
    }

    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($_GET['cat']);
    echo "</pre>";
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($_GET['type']);
    echo "</pre>";
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($querycat);
    echo "</pre>";
    die();

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE visible='1' $querycat ORDER BY $sorting",$link);
```

Comment: Старайтесь отвечать не только для задающих вопросы,и как нибудь прокомментировать участки кода, чтоб легче было оценить ответ